# Chrome is claiming my antivirus is "incompatible application"

Tags: google-chrome, anti-virus

Beginning yesterday 2018-07-05, each time I start Chrome, it opens to this URL:

```
chrome://settings/incompatibleApplications
```

[image]

ESET Endpoint Antivirus is definitely not anything strange and there is no chance I am going to remove it. It has been on my Windows 10 machine for over two years (and is mandated by our company policy); and it is fully updated.

Why would Chrome be claiming it is incompatible??

How can I prevent this incorrect message from showing?

EDIT: Here is the ESET endpoint dialog. Version 6.6.2086.0
[image: ESET endpoint version screenshot]

EDIT 2: SSL/TLS filtering is *not* enabled.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you running? Someone on the [ESET Forum](https://forum.eset.com/topic/15877-chrome-warning-to-remove-eset-endpoint-antivirus/) posted the same issue a few days ago. Someone was unable to reproduce the problem. Maybe you could help add to the forum too.

Comment: With a similar looking issue someone else said to do a hard reset of Google Chrome. Although this wasn't with the same application, you could try it. The steps are listed here on the [Google Chrome Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/_6REME5o47U)

Comment: "not anything strange"? The page isn't saying it's strange or malicious. The page is saying it's _incompatible with Chrome_. Do not assume antivirus software is infallible.

Comment: What version of ESET Endpoint are you running?

Comment: Related to this? https://blog.chromium.org/2017/11/reducing-chrome-crashes-caused-by-third.html

Comment: Or this? https://www.chromium.org/administrators/err_eset_anti_virus_ssl_interception

Comment: @DavidMarshall : I don't have that ESET version ... but what appears to be the equivalent, SSL/TLS filtering, is *NOT* enabled.

Comment: @HelpingHand: Quite possibly this is it. I am, however, not going to take Chrome's suggestion, ever. I am not uninstalling ESET, and unless given specific instructions either by ESET or by Google relating to ESET, I am not going to make any changes to my configuration. I will just have to live with the warning, I guess, and curse at Chrome every time it starts.

Comment: @grawity: I am far more likely to assume browsers are malicious (or subverted) than that antivirus packages are fallible.

Comment: Voting to close my own question: duplicate of [Disable "Update or remove incompatible applications" message in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/1338354/disable-update-or-remove-incompatible-applications-message-in-chrome)