# Disable "Update or remove incompatible applications" message in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Whenever I open an incognito window in Chrome, it opens a Settings tab with the address `chrome://settings/incompatibleApplications` which says "Update or remove incompatible applications", telling me that an application could prevent Chrome from working properly:

[image]

The application in question is my antivirus program. I checked if I can update the antivirus program and I can't, and I obviously don't want to uninstall it. Clicking the "REMOVE..." link just opens a Windows Settings window where I can uninstall my antivirus program.

Also, I haven't noticed the program cause any problems in Chrome, so there isn't really any reason I would uninstall it.

I tried clicking on the "Learn how to update applications" link, but that sent me to a help page which just explained how to open that settings page manually.

I think that it's very annoying that Chrome opens that page automatically. Is there a way I can prevent Chrome from doing so?

Comment: I would assume that the antivirus somehow keeps Chrome's 'incognito' window from being fully incognito, and that's your warning. So even if it works fine, your wife might be able to see next day tat you watched porn or whatever.

Comment: @Aganju I use incognito mostly when I want to access a site being logged out without having to log out and then back in manually, so I don't really care if the history of sites I visited in incognito is accessible somewhere.

Comment: Also got this issue on a machine - and one of the applications it wants me to remove is Dropbox which is 100% up to date (v56 at time of writting). The user hadn't noticed it being linked to incognito though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also got this problem, and so did a bit of digging.

According to [this answer](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/pTxH3Yu7XVc) from a Chrome Dev, there is nothing you can do about it. They say:

> This is related to a new feature that aims to prevent third party software from injecting into Chrome's processes and interfering with its code.
>
> To keep things simple we warn about all injected software, without making value judgments.

Thankfully, they also say:

> Note that soon we will actually start blocking software from injecting, at which point this warning will cease to show.

So I guess all that can be done is wait from them to move from warning to blocking. The answer was posted in July 2018, so I imagine soon could be anywhere from the next 2 months to next year.

Comment: What if the application it will be blocking is my network driver?

Comment: @Jungkook note that all they are blocking is the process interfering with Chrome's process. And by interfering, they mean bypassing security controls. So I'd be *very* worried if my network driver was trying to inject things into Chrome.

Comment: Now Chrome is claiming Adobe Acrobat DC is a problem! wtf

Comment: @CalvT What can I do to prevent that? [link to screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/ESrYMaj)